# 'NumpyArrayWrapper' object is not iterable, when using pickle.load(f)

Tags: python, object, pickle, iterable

I have already saved the file using `pickle.dump()` but when i try to load it using `pickle.load()` the following error appear.

`TypeError: 'NumpyArrayWrapper' object is not iterable`

My code looks like this.

```
with open('sample.pickle', 'rb') as f:
    x, y = pickle.load(f)
```

x and y are actually the vector representation of words. Which are then stored in the sample.pickle file. Its code is (if it is useful)

```
with open('sample.pickle','w') as f:
pickle.dump([x,y],f)
```

I have no idea about the object is not iterable error. Please help if you know anything about it. Thanks in advance.